# xcodebuild: error: 'APP\ Name.xcworkspace' does not exist if my project have a space in the name

Tags: swift, xcode, codemagic

My app can not be build if the xcworkspace name has a space, do you know how I can include an space in this command?

xcodebuild build 
-workspace "App\ Name.xcworkspace" 
-scheme "App\ Name"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you don't need to use backslash `\` if it's already double quoted.